# JavaFX 2: Color Picker without custom color

Tags: javafx-2, color-picker

Is there a way to render a color picker without the "Custom colors" option?

Or is there a way to disable the "Custom Color" option from the color picker?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this but haven't tried it, maybe the customizable color picker you're looking for?

https://github.com/fxexperience/code/blob/master/FXExperienceControls/src/com/fxexperience/javafx/scene/control/colorpicker/ColorPickerPopover.java

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the hyperlink together with the separator and the excess space that remains when just removing those two:

```
.color-palette .hyperlink, .color-palette .separator {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.color-palette {
    -fx-padding: 15 15 -30 15;
}
```

! Note that the style needs to be added to the scene Object to take effect.

Answer (score -1):

Since i was also searching for a simple solution.
If you want to use the default color picker you can use this style class:

```
.color-palette > .hyperlink {
    visibility: hidden ;
}
```